# To give JS variable as data attribute in object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

To give Javascript variable as data value in object tag I used

```
var one= "http://localhost:3000/?id=";
var two = one + fort + "&to=" + too;       

$("#chatArea").html('<object data= +two />');
```

But it's not working.
How can I hand the var into my data attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use string concatenation

```
$("#chatArea").html('<object data="'+ two + '"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation:

```
$("#chatArea").html('<object data="' + two + '" />');
```

Or you can use the [`$(html, attributes)` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes), which takes an html string for a new element and an object with the attributes for the new element:

```
$("#chatArea").html($('<object/>', { data: two }));
```